# Cannot Update: Failed to update “Shortcuts”

Tags: apt, odin, app-shortcuts, update-manager

I have Elementary OS 6 Odin installed on a laptop that can triple boot Windows, Elementary and Zorin OS. When I try to update it from the ApppCenter, I get this message (can't install any software too):

[image]

> Error while installing package: installed org.gnome.fileroller package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

At the terminal, I get this after `sudo apt update`

> 8 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

> W: mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/dists/focal-updates/InRelease: No system certificates available. Try installing ca-certificates.

> W: https://la.mirrors.clouvider.net/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/43ee4298b0875017554ed312414449b7e8cfa6055a0e47cef9da74350bf9355d: No system certificates available. Try installing ca-certificates.

> W: https://mirrors.bloomu.edu/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/universe/dep11/by-hash/SHA256/fc3d0692ad719efd35181078eabd24df193ee3834ec04cca52593b550a9917bd: No system certificates available. Try installing ca-certificates.

Update 1:

After `sudo apt install --reinstall ca-certificates`, [this came out.](https://pastebin.com/UBUrqTFS)

These are my [certificates](https://pastebin.com/vb2wMGxd)  from `ls -l /etc/ssl/certs`.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing `ca-certificates` from the Terminal? `sudo apt install --reinstall ca-certificates`. If this doesn't work, could you [edit] your question to include the Terminal output of: `ls -l /etc/ssl/certs`? This will show which certificate files are on your machine (to identify which ones are not) 